# How to handle a single value in Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

Let's assume that we have this store:

```
// initialState.js file
export default = {
  _token: 'a hashed long string from server',
  user: {
    key: value,
    ... many more
  }
  .. many more
}
```

and here is the reducer for token ONLY:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes'
import initialState from './initialState'

export default function tokenReducer(state = initialState._token, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.CHANGE_TOKEN:
        console.log(action.payload) //  a new hashed long string from server
        return action.payload // payload is a token string that comes from server
     default: 
       return state

  }
}
```

Is it ok?

I mean that I used ONLY `initialState.token` part of store in my reducer in order to prevent from returning the whole state using `Object.assign` or spread operator, I just updated the string (the token).

Is this is the correct way to change only one string value from store or I should return the whole state and use `Object.assign` like below?

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes'
import initialState from './initialState'

export default function tokenReducer(state = initialState._token, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.CHANGE_TOKEN:
        console.log(action.payload) //  a new hashed long string from server
        return {
           ...state ,
           Object.assign({}, state, {_token: action.payload})
        }
     default: 
       return state

  }
}
```

Comment: Your first case and the second case is a little bit different. First of all, if you use a reducer like this, your `tokenReducer` state will be just a **string** in the first case. But, in your second case you are returning an object and there you are trying to spread your state, a string! and some wrong object key assign, no key there (`Object.assign` line). So, probably this is not what you think here. Maybe you can use a reducer for a single state property like this but how is your app's design, how will you use your other parts of the state?

Comment: i am currently using the first reducer , and i think that something is wrong with it , i don't know why but i think that something is wrong , that is why i posted this question here , first reducer is the correct way to handle the issue or the second one...

Comment: The second one **does not** work as it is. You are manipulating the state wrong. You have one piece of state there: **token string**. No objects, no other thing. So, if you want to keep a token string state, just go with the first one, there is nothing wrong there. But, as I said in the previous comment, we can't be sure without seeing your whole state structure of your app. For example, how do you plan using other pieces of your initial state?

Comment: If you toss this state to a different reducer then why do you keep `_token` there if you don't mutate it in the other reducer?

Comment: There is no wrong with the first approach actually.